# Angular filter,sort and paginate table

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am using Angular5 for a web app that I'm learning upon.
In one page, I need to have a table that lists information that is returned from an Restful endpoint.
Example it returns :

Name, LastName, Age, Group, and such things.

On the client-side, I need to have sorting on every column header, and filtering based on a dropdown option.
What is the best way to do this ?
Using something like [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/) ?
Or using something else ?
I am just asking about best practices and how such things are normally done, as this is the first time I'm using angular.

I am using Bootstrap 4 with it, also have ng-bootstrap.
Thanks

Comment: Have you considered PrimeNG controls? http://primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable does what you're looking for. I've been using them without any hassle.

Comment: Is it a good choice ?
Because I wanted to use primefaces for calendars, and I was suggested that i use ng-bootstrap since it's already in the project.
If I install primeNG it will have everything else that I won't use. Is it worth it to only install it for datatable?

Comment: You install the whole package, but you can just load what you need importing just the modules of those components that you're planning to use. I think that's the most important thing, without mention that you're not reinventing the wheel and focusing on the business logic of your app.

Answer (score 2):

Using bootstrap and angular I indicate this component: [angular2-datatable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-datatable#mfdata-directive)

**step 1 => install**: `npm i -S angular2-datatable`

**step 2 =>  appModule.ts** add imports:

```
import {NgModule} from "@angular/core";
...
import {DataTableModule} from "angular2-datatable";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        ...
        DataTableModule
    ],
    ...
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**step 3 => yourComponent.ts**

```
...
export class DemoComponent implements OnInit {
    public data;
    public filterQuery = "";
    public rowsOnPage = 10;
    public sortBy = "age";
    public sortOrder = "asc";

constructor() {}

ngOnInit() {

this.data = [
  {
    "name": "Wing",
    "age": 25
  },
  {
    "name": "Whitney",
    "age": 32
  }];
}

public toInt(num: string) {
    return +num;
}

public sortByWordLength = (a: any) => {
    return a.name.length;
}
```

**step 4 => yourComponent.html**

```
<table class="table table-striped" [mfData]="data" #mf="mfDataTable" [mfRowsOnPage]="5">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="width: 70%">
            <mfDefaultSorter by="name">Name</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>

        <th style="width: 20%">
            <mfDefaultSorter by="age">Age</mfDefaultSorter>
        </th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
        <td>{{item.name}}</td>
        <td class="text-right">{{item.age}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <mfBootstrapPaginator [rowsOnPageSet]="[5,10,25]"></mfBootstrapPaginator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

[`plunker`](http://plnkr.co/edit/PxBaZs?p=preview)

Comment: For Angular 6, and later, you can use this instead. It's a fork with minimal changes. https://github.com/PascalHonegger/ng-datatable